# What does the word ''authority'' mean?

Tags: meaning-in-context, phrase-meaning, word-meaning, phrase-usage

In the following passage, I know here the word "authority" should not be the meaning: "political or administrative power and control", it's not suitable in this context.

May be, I think the meaning of it will be "tradition or rite and ritual". I'm not sure.

how should I understand this phrase "Blind faith in authority" or the word "authority"?

The contexts:

> Inasmuch as the Buddha teaches that all genuine progress on the path of virtue is necessarily dependent upon one’s own understanding and insight, all dogmatism is excluded from the Buddha’s teaching. Blind faith in **authority** is rejected by the Buddha, and is entirely opposed to the spirit of his teaching.

"Fundamentals of Buddhism" by Nyanatiloka Mahåthera, Page. 5

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The definition from [Merriam-Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/authority) that best fits is:

> **4 c :** an individual cited or appealed to as an expert

Buddha teaches not to believe what someone says simply because they are acknowledged as an expert, or have the title of expert.

Comment: Thanks a lot...

Answer (score 3):

It doesn't mean quite either of those things.

It means "somebody or something outside you telling you the answers or what to do".

It's sense 4 at [Wiktionary](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/authority#Noun):

> Status as a trustworthy source of information, reputation for mastery or expertise; or claim to such status or reputation.

Comment: you mean ''outward things''?

Comment: I want more and clear answer please...

Comment: I believe I have given you a clear answer (with a source). What is it you are asking for beyond that?

Comment: Thanks,  I got it...